# What is the maximum number of tags supported?

Tags: macos, finder, hfs+, finder-tag

My concern is that [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/295151/mac-os-x-is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-color-ls-output-according-to-finder) implies that there is a bitfield of a fixed size in the HFS+ extended attribute that is used for storing tag flags. Or maybe that just for the first N tags, and it has some way of handling the overflow case?

What is the maximum number of unique Finder tags that can be created? I am interested in the answer for OS versions 10.10 - 10.12

Comment: Colors and tags are two different things, the (probably outdated) answer refers to colors. But let's see whether somebody can provide an answer with references to Apple's documentation on the topic (assuming there is one).